# Keep set button colour when leaving activity and returning

Tags: android, button, android-activity, colors

I have the following code in my main activity. When I enter the main activity in the app and press a button it changes the colour of the button as desired.

The problem I have is that if I leave this activity, go to another activity and then return, the button colour has changed back to the default colour.

Is anyone able to provide suggestions on how to maintain the button colour.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onClick(final View v) {


    //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
    //Inflating the Popup using xml file
    popup.getMenuInflater()
            .inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) { 


    v.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ff69b4"), 
    PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a sugest to you, maybe it work...

When you press the button you can save the button color on a sharedPreferences variable. Then, when you open your activity again, inside of OnCreate you check the sharedPreferences variable and get the color that you saved before and set to your button.

Sorry for bad english =)